# Best Practice to Hold UIImage's in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiimageview

I have a lot of `UIImage`'s that I need to hold in memory during one particular action.

The best way I managed to hold images is to convert them to `NSData` and store in `NSMutableArray`. Later I would loop through array and convert `NSData` to `UIImage` objects again to reuse each image (I really merge them all into one single piece).

However, if there are 10 or more images in array my app crashes. Saving them to hard drive instead of `NSMutableArray` will add a lot of processing time for user.

What's the best practice to handle a large amount of images on the fly?

Comment: Why do you need to convert them to NSData?

Comment: Why do all the conversion? What's wrong with just storing the UIImage in an array?

Comment: Why dont you just save the datapath to an array and call the data when you need it?

Comment: @Tim I convert to NSData because it seems to better handle larger amount of images in array vs just UIImage objects. I think I found out that by research online but this may be wrong.

Comment: @JustinAmberson can you confirm there is no difference?

Comment: @SpaceDust I do not have paths. I am cutting one huge image into pieces on the fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that you can store more images in the array before crashing if you store the UIImage directly. It costs memory to convert from NSData to UIImage and back.

However, you still have limited memory. If these images can change in size, the number you can have in the array before crashing will be unknown. If this is the case, it might be time to start looking at caching the data to the `tmp` folder.

Regardless, the best practice is to hold references to objects directly in an array rather than convert them to NSData. Storing direct references also allows reference counting to work its magic, generally requiring less copying of data in memory, reducing the memory footprint and improving performance.